# Debugger missing in Netbeans after upgrading OS X to Yosemite

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, osx-yosemite

After upgrading my Mac to Yosemite I cannot longer use the debugger as long as it doesn't appear and gives an error when I try to use it. When I start the debugger this (http://imgur.com/jY8YSv2) appears, but when I compile & run it it works perfectly.

In the preferences menu, I can set a path for the debugger but it's blank, how can I know where my debugger is installed?

I have Xcode installed & also reinstalled Java, I might have missed a step. Is there a guide/steps to follow to make it work?

Thank you in advance.